# How to reduce image size from the Flickr API using Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, image-processing, flickr, image-loading

I am using google app engine python to build an app that gets pictures from the Flickr API. I am using two APIs; one that returns the most recent pictures posted and another that returns pictures based on searches. Because I am displaying 50 pictures from the first api (automatically loaded on page load) and another 100 pictures when users perform a search, the page takes forever to load every time I perform a search. I would like to know if there is a way to select only pictures of a certain size (say, less than 200k) when parsing the data from the API. The objects that Flickr provide don't have information about image size so I cannot parse the data based on the object info. Here is an example of the object:

```
  {photos: 
      {page: 1,pages: 198413,perpage: 100,total: "19841218",
          photo:[
                  {id:"14236785916",
                   owner: "53858541@N05",
                   secret: "ef9e745ba4",
                   server: "5591",
                   farm:6,
                   title: "bright",
                   ispublic: 1,
                   isfriend: 0,
                   isfamily: 0}
                 ]
      }
  }
```

I wanted to know if there is any other method. I want to keep the number of pictures I have now.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a limitation of a client library that you're using? This doc link seems to suggest you can get the size https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html?

Comment: Thank you. Totally oversaw this. I will try it and see how it goes but it looks like it is what I was looking for!